# Would people welcome having a mtpro (short for Mathtime Professional) tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

There seems to be no ready-made tag for discussions of the pros and cons -- see, e.g., [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63545/5001) -- of the Mathtime Professional fonts package. I know it doesn't come up very often on TeX.SE, but it's actually a rather nifty package (everybody's reservations about superwide accents and 5cm-tall summation symbols notwithstanding).

I've noticed that the recently released `newtxmath` package consciously uses output from the `mtpro2` package as a yardstick to measure the quality of its own output (and, importantly, how much better `newtxmath` is than `txfonts`).

Much more information about the Mathtime Professional font package may be found at [this site](http://pctex.com/mtpro2.html).

What do others think?

Answer (score 8):

No particular objection,

There is [mathpazo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathpazo) and [newtx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newtx)  [neo-euler](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neo-euler) any other math font specific tags?
[libertine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libertine) is another font specific tag. It seems like there should be consistency if we are going to encourage this, for example whether the tag is named after (and refers to) a particular font family or a particular font-related package.

Answer (score 6):

I would definitely welcome such a tag. As someone who uses mtpro2 I have asked several questions dealing with the package here, specially since the people who sell the font don't respond to the problems and the material on their website is outdated.