# Application of the {mtpro} tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

Quite recently Miko introduced the `mtpro` tag for questions related to the `mtpro` and `mtpro2` fonts with [Would people welcome having a mtpro (short for Mathtime Professional) tag?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/would-people-welcome-having-a-mtpro-short-for-mathtime-professional-tag) .

But now it feels to me (without disrespect for his contributions) that he is somehow pushing those fonts a little bit too much. In particular I am concerned about tagging questions where the original poster had not thought about the `mtpro` package. (Actually I made a similar mistake myself and [was corrected by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/65599/revisions))

So I looked for a guideline and it seems this has come up before in [Adding tags to a question in accordance with a provided answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/577/adding-tags-to-a-question-in-accordance-with-a-provided-answer). According to the suggestion there I removed some of the tags, where the question doesn't meantion `mtpro`. Nevertheless there are still some where I'm unsure of what to do, as Mico's answers there, using `mtpro`, are the (as good as) accepted ones:

- [Big tilde in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode)
- [Big integral sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign)
- [Suggest a "nice" font family for my basic LaTeX template (text and math)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59702/suggest-a-nice-font-family-for-my-basic-latex-template-text-and-math-i-am)

Because of this and the fact, that many currently active users where not on TeX.SX back then, I'm asking for a suggestion on how to handle such cases.

Comment: I've removed the tag in the three cases linked: none of the questions are about Mathtime Pro at all.